# Как ограничить получение данных с сервера?

Tags: java, spring, api, backend

У меня есть 1_000_000 записей на сервере, при запросе на получение данных я хочу получить не все сразу, а  порционно, например, по 100 при каждом обращении. Есть ли какие-то best practice по решению данной проблемы?

Comment: да , это называется пагинация. очень легко нагуглить

Comment: Да, это повсеместное решение - использовать **постраничный вывод**, пример - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#filter-and-paginate-data

Answer (score 4):

Обычно в таких ситуациях вводятся дополнительные параметры запроса, например `offset` и `pageSize`, которые указывает серверу, с каким смещением от первой записи возвращать данные в этот раз, и сколько вернуть записей всего.

Например, если мы хотим получить от сервера записи со 115 по 215:

```
GET my-api.com/notes?offset=115&pageSize=100
```

На сервере парсим эти параметры, и достаём из БД нужное количество записей.

Если сервер в очередной раз вернул меньше записей, чем `pageSize`, значит это последняя страница, мы дочитали до конца, и дальше запрашивать нет смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Немного дополню ответ [@coolsv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/215728/coolsv). Раз вы используете Spring, то вы, вероятно, используете  в качестве DAO свою реализацию `JpaRepository`, которая выглядит как-то так:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface MyObjectDao extends JpaRepository<MyObjectDao, Integer> {

    Set<MyObject> findAll();
}
```

Так вот. Когда мы делаем пагинацию, мы не выгружаем все данные клиенту, а только их часть. То же самое и с базой данных. Вам не обязательно выгружать все элементы из БД, чтобы потом в программе отобрать только некоторые и отдать их клиенту. Вы можете сразу выбрать из базы данных только нужные элементы. Для этого вы можете использовать объект `Pageable`, который содержит данные для пагинации и передаётся в методы `JpaRepository`:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface MyObjectDao extends JpaRepository<MyObjectDao, Integer> {

    Set<MyObject> findAll(Pageable pagination);
}
```

Создать объект `Pageable` довольно легко:

```
Pageable pagination = PageRequest.of(0, 20, Sort.Direction.ASC, "name");
```

Первым параметром передаётся номер страница *(нумерация начинается с нуля)*. Второй параметр - количество элементов на странице. Третий параметр - это сортировка, ASC или DESC. Четвёртым параметром вы можете передать свойство вашего `MyObject`, по которому будет происходить сортировка.

Используя пагинацию на уровне базы данных вы можете улучшить производительность программы.

Answer (score 2):

Хочу написать про случай, когда используется СУБД для хранения данных.

Решения основанные на offset описанные в других ответах очень распостранены и хорошо поддерживаются в ORM-ах. Но, к сожалению, производительность решения основанного на offset плохо масштабируется. Даже на объемах меньших чем 1 млн. уже будет разница. [Тут](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way) этого хорошо описано для postgres, но это справедливо для [любой](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) реляционной СУБД.

Производительность страдает при получении страниц с большими offset-ами. Грубо говоря, проблема в том, что БД не может эффективно использовать индексы, для того чтобы избежать сортировки необходимой для вычисления элементов, которые сдвинуты от начала на заданную величину offset.

Поэтому, лучше использовать альтернативный подход (его называют seek). Вместо offset, т.е. сдвига от начала, нужно передавать идентификатор последнего прочитано элемента на предыдущей странице. Т.е. API выглядит так:

```
GET my-api.com/notes?last_seen_note_id=115&pageSize=100
```

Если `last_seen_note_id` не передали, то значит, что читать нужно с самого начала (это эквивалентно `offset==0`).

В БД в этом случае будет выполнен запрос типа:

```
SELECT *
FROM notes
WHERE id > :last_seen_note_id
ORDER BY <критерий сортировки>
LIMIT pageSize
```

А такой запрос при правильных индексах будет работать одинаково хорошо как для первых, так и для последних страниц.

И еще один важный момент.
Так как результат получается не одним запросом, а несколькими, то данные за это время могли уже поменяться, например, что-то добавилось или удалилось. При неправильном выборе критерия сортировки, может так получиться, что данные сдвинутся и какие-то записи будут пропущены или прочитаны два раза. И решение с offset очень чувствительно к этой проблеме, тогда как seek позволяет ее избежать.