# С каждым запросом растет время получения результата

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, spring, hibernate

Разрабатываю сервисы с использованием java spring, postgresql и hibernate. Один сервис отправляет другому запросы. Сервис, который принимает запросы, загружает данные из БД, проводит вычисления, загружает результаты в БД при каждом новом запросе.
Процесс загрузки данных из БД выглядит следующим образом:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("give me some data");
List resultList = query.getResultList();
```

При первом запросе выполнение query.getResultList() занимает около 120 миллисекунд. При втором запросе - 190 миллисекунд, третьем - 255 миллисекунд и так далее. Хотя размер выгружаемых данных всегда один и тот же. Такими темпами обработка одного запроса будет занимать более одного часа.
Кто-нибудь может подсказать в чем может быть дело?

Comment: В такой постановке вопроса, в чем дело не подскажем. Нужно смотреть, где это время теряется. Для начала - посмотреть на стороне БД, занимает ли запрос одинаковое время. Далее, запросы абсолютно одинаковые или чем-то отличаются, если да чем? Действительно ли каждый следующий запрос выполняется на почти такое же время дольше? До какой итерации доходили и сколько занимал запрос? Вы их выполняете в цикле один за другим?

Comment: @RomanKonoval 1) со стороны БД запросы всегда занимают около 120 мс (проверил через pgAdmin). 2) Запросы в целом индентичные, меняется только пара параметров для того, чтобы из БД выгружать не все объекты из таблицы, а только некоторые, отфильтрованные. 3) Засекал время выполнения query.getResultList() через System.nanoTime(). В каждом новом запросе к сервису (не к БД) время увеличивалось. 4) Доходил до 100 итерации, и один расчет в сервисе занимал до 20 минут (в сервисе идет несколько аналогичных запросов в БД). 5) По сути, да. Одна группа расчетов и запросов в БД - это одна итерация в цикле.

Comment: Отвечать нужно не в комментариях, а уточнять вопрос кнопкой "править". Запрос случайно не постраничное чтение с `offset ... limit ...`. Если так, то это [ожидаемо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1283692/218971). pgAdmin - это не показатель, у вас же проблема в приложении, нужно мерять время именно тех вызовов, которые медленные.

Comment: @RomanKonoval спасибо за наставления, я решил проблему, но не до конца понимаю, почему это помогло. Оказывается, что сервис не посылал запрос второму сервису в цикле. Сам цикл с необходимыми данными был реализован во втором сервисе (упс :) ). То есть сменил архитектуру из СЕРВИС1[запрос->] СЕРВИС2[ЦИКЛ ОБЪЕКТОВ ДЛЯ РАСЧЕТА:{загрузка данных из БД, расчет, загрузка в БД}] в СЕРВИС1[ЦИКЛ ОБЪЕКТОВ ДЛЯ РАСЧЕТА:{запрос->}] СЕРВИС2[загрузка данных из БД, расчет, загрузка в БД]. Тогда время выполнения query.getResultList() всегда составляет около 120 мс. И нет, offset и limit в запросах не участвовали